# how to convert Arabic text to English in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, arabic

I got a dataset from a government (Dubai) website and I want to do basic data analysis. But one of the variables is recorded in Arabic language. Is there a way to convert it to English in R?

[image]

if i am not wrong, **acci_name** defines type of road accident. I want to convert that column to English to carry out EDA. thanks in advance.

Comment: Translate it outside R, maybe Google Translate, then import.

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution based on [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/translate-a-pandas-data-frame-using-googletrans-library-fb0aa7fca592) if anyone is interested. Python library **googletrans** can be used to translate text.

here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator

#create a translator object
translator = Translator()

df = pd.read_csv("Traffic_Incidents.csv")

translations = {}
unique_values = df["acci_name"].unique()

#by default it identifies the source lang and converts it into eng
for element in unique_values:
    translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
```

translations dict can be converted to a dataframe and joined with the df

here is the translation for each string
[image]